# Relationship between averages of $x^tx$ and $xx^t$ for column vector $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, finance, economics

If we have data set $x$ as $m$ of  $n \times 1$ vectors, and we know the average over index $m$ of $xx^t$ is $<xx^t> = C$, where $C$ is $ n \times n$ matrix.  What is the average of scalar $ x^tx$? I came up with two ways and not sure which one is more suitable or which one is wrong:

(1). Using $tr(AB) =tr(BA)$, $<x^tx> = <tr(x^tx) >=tr(<xx^t>) = tr(C)$

(2) $<x^tx> \simeq \sqrt{<x^txx^tx>} = \sqrt{<x^tCx>} = \sqrt{<tr(x^tCx)>} =  \sqrt{tr(<Cxx^t>)} = \sqrt{tr(C^2)}$

**EDIT** (1) is correct after modification from joriki's answer below.  (2) is wrong for two reasons: a. the first $\simeq$ is not a good approximation since variance of $x^tx$ may be large' b. the first equal sign to replace $xx^t$ by $C$ is wrong since there terms of $x^t$, $xx^t$, $x$ are perfectly correlated through $x$, therefore $<x^txx^tx> \neq <x^t<xx^t>x>$. This step underestimates the result.

related question [Expected value of $x^t\Sigma x$ for multivariate normal distribution $N(0,\Sigma)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827971/expected-value-of-xt-sigma-x-for-multivariate-normal-distribution-n0-sigma)

Comment: $C$ has at most 1 nonzero eigenvalue, so (1) and (2) say the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines are wrong but the first one happens to end up with the right result nevertheless.

The first one is wrong because you drop the average in the first step, whereas you can only drop it in the last step; in the last step you replace $xx^\top$ by $C$ even though $C$ is defined as the average of that quantity. If you take the average of all intermediate results, you get a correct derivation of the result.

The second one is wrong because the expectation of $x^\top x$ isn't the square root of the expectation of its square. (In fact the difference between the expectation of the square and the square of the expectation is the variance.) Also again you can't replace $xx^\top$ by $C$ because $C$ is the average of that quantity; and you can't just drop the average in the third step.

Overall I get the impression that you seem to be confusing taking the average with taking the trace; these are related in other contexts, but not here, where the average is being taken over the data points and not over the vector components.

Comment: I guess the rank is min(m,n) as I updated question?

Comment: @ahala: I don't know what you're talking about. The question doesn't mention a rank (neither the original question nor the edited one). What you added to the question is wrong and seems to indicate a misunderstanding of my answer. As snarfblaat had already pointed out, the two right-hand results are equal. The second chain of equations still contains some of the errors I pointed out, so there's point of deducing anything from its result. Also I don't know why you think that this difference is a variance (and of what).

Comment: as edited question, considering x is m observations of a multivariate variable ~ $N(0, \Sigma)$ C is then sample variance with more than 1 non zero eigenvalues. we could talk about variance of x'x over m observations.

Comment: @ahala: You're right about the eigenvalues; I removed the reference to snarfblaat's comment from the answer. You're also right that if $x$ has mean zero, $C$ is the (co)variance matrix of $x$. Sure we can talk about the variance of $x^\top x$. I still don't understand what you mean by the remark about the variance being negative or by the remark about the rank.